# Trying to add up the values of multiple keys in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, javascript-objects

I'm creating a mock shopping cart and I'm having a little trouble with my function that updates the cart. When a user adds something to the shopping cart, the **item name** and the desired **quantity** is stored in a `sessionStorage` object. The `updateCart()` function uses the data from this object.

I'm trying to:
1. loop through the `sessionStorage` object and obtain the item name and quantity
2. Multiply the quantity by the price for each item
3. Add up all the item totals into one grand total

The third part is tricky.

**HTML**

```
<div id="Burger">6.50</div>
<div id="Cheeseburger">7.50</div>
<div id="Hotdog">4.00</div>
```

**sessionStorage object**

```
{
    "Burger" : "2",
    "Cheeseburger" : "3",
    "Hotdog" : "1"
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function updateCart() {

    var storage = window.sessionStorage;
    var sumtotal = 0;

    for ( var i in storage ) {

        var item = new Object();

        item.name = i;
        item.quantity = parseFloat( storage[i] );
        item.price = parseFloat( $("#" + item.name).text() );
        item.total = item.price * item.quantity;

        sumtotal = parseFloat( sumtotal + item.total );

        console.log(sumtotal);

    }
}
```

Can't seem get the grand/sum total to work. Help?

Comment: Check your `storage` variable. My guess is that it's empty in your `updateCart` function.

Comment: Browser? Environment? If IE9+ used in local environment, `sessionStorage` is undefined, though it works in network.

Comment: Latest Chrome, OS X. The variable isn't empty. Console log spits out data once for each item.

Comment: Works fine if `storage` is what it is supposed to be: http://jsfiddle.net/Xd82V/. What exactly "does not work"?

Comment: And if you add a console.log(item) after setting the properties?

Comment: side note: use `var item = {};` instead of `var item = new Object();`

Comment: @FelixKling I dunno what's wrong with my code then. It works fine when I have one item in the shopping cart, but seems to corrupt when I have more than 1 item. The values are off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this line:

```
sumtotal = parseFloat( sumtotal + item.total );
```

Should be:

```
sumtotal += parseFloat( item.total );
```

Now you get only the last value of `item.total`.

Comment: It was a parseFloat error. I had a few more that were messing with the values. Good eye, thank you!

Comment: I must be blind, I don't see the difference and I don't even understand why parseFloat is needed here.

Comment: @Teemu but you're not adding "Burger", you're adding item.total which is a number

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is how you're supposed to use sessionStorage. Instead, you need to create an object - called order for example - that will host your numbers:

```
var storage=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("order"));
```

See the [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd82V/2/).

Comment: And store the object as a sessionStorage variable? But how would that be any different?

Comment: @muppethead it seems that you found your error. But my point is that if you use the sessionStorage object directly this might interfere with other scripts in the same domain that also use it.

Comment: Ah well, thanks for the advice. I'll just keep an eye out if I use the sessionStorage object on my domain again.

Comment: @muppethead I have added a demo and removed the useless parseFloat. I don't think the other answer does anything at all (cf. my comment).